# Computer freeze in Windows 10 after upgrade to SSD

Tags: ssd, windows-10, freeze

I just upgraded my computer with an SSD.

I installed Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu 14.04 on the SSD.

When I boot into Ubuntu, the computer is working 100%, no problem, but in Windows one time that I tried to install Windows it failed, and now after I successfully installed Windows, sometimes the computer just freezes and I have to reset it. (No reset button, if I press the reset button the computer does not see the SSD).

My motherboard is DG31PR (There isn't AHCI mode in it). The SSD is Samsung 850 EVO 250GB.

In the Windows 10 cmd window running the command: `fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify` gives the result `DisableDeleteNotify = 0` so TRIM support is enabled.

I have read very much about this topic, but nothing I read solved my problem.

Comment: In Windows 10 TRIM enabled automatically, and `fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify` get `DisableDeleteNotify = 0`, so, it's enabled.